# Secured users created in grails integration test are unauthorized but bootstrapped ones are

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-rest-api

I'm using [Grails Spring Security Core](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/latest/index.html) and the [Grails Spring Security REST plugin](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/) and I'm just starting to get things set up. I initialized the plugins with a `User` class and an `Authority` class (defaults) and went to write an integration test, following a [guide I found on the Grails website](http://guides.grails.org/grails-test-security/guide/index.html).

It said to put the following in an integration test:

```
def "test a user with the role ROLE_BOSS is able to access /api/announcements url"() {
    when: 'login with the sherlock'
    RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
    def resp = rest.post("http://localhost:${serverPort}/api/login") { 
        accept('application/json')
        contentType('application/json')
        json {
            username = 'sherlock'
            password = 'elementary'
        }
    }

    then:
    resp.status == 200
    resp.json.roles.find { it == 'ROLE_BOSS' }
}
```

I went ahead and did something similar and it worked with a bootstrapped `User`, but when I tried to do the exact same test with a `User` created in the test method itself, it would fail with a `401` HTTP response code.

The code I'm trying to run:

```
void "check get access token"() {
    given:
    RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
    new User(username: "securitySpecTestUserName", password: "securitySpecTestPassword").save(flush: true)
    assert User.count == 2

    when:
    def resp = rest.post("http://localhost:${serverPort}/api/login") {
        accept('application/json')
        contentType('application/json')
        json {
            username = "securitySpecTestUserName"
            password = "securitySpecTestPassword"
        }
    }

    then:
    resp.status == 200
}
```

Note that the `User.count == 2` assertion passes because there is one `User` in `Bootstrap.groovy` and the one create in the test method.

Why does this work and pass with the bootstrapped `User` without any issues at all but not the one created in the method? Is there a way I can write this integration test so that I can test the `/api/login` endpoint included in the `grails-spring-security-rest` plugin in this way?

Comment: could you check if the user is enabled, accountLocked, accountExpired is set to true?

Comment: @dynamo unfortunately `enabled = true`, `accountExpired = false`, `accountLocked = false`, `passwordExpired = false`, just like the bootstrapped user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User you create in the given section is in a transaction that has not been committed.  When you make the REST call, the api/login controller will be run in a new transaction that cannot see your un-committed User.

A few options (there are others)...

1. Create User in BootStrap.groovy

   ```
   def init = { servletContext ->
     environments {
       test {
         new User(username: "securitySpecTestUserName", password: "securitySpecTestPassword").save(flush: true)
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Make REST calls to create the User - assuming you have such functionality
3. Create User in setup

   ```
   @Integration
   @Rollback
   class UserIntSpec extends Specification {

     def setup() {
       new User(username: "securitySpecTestUserName", password: "securitySpecTestPassword").save(flush: true)
     }

     void "check get access token"() {
       given:
       RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()

       when:
       def response = rest.post("http://localhost:${serverPort}/api/login") {
         accept('application/json')
         contentType('application/json')
         json {
           username = "securitySpecTestUserName"
           password = "securitySpecTestPassword"
         }
       }

      then:
      response.status == HttpServletResponse.SC_OK

      when:
      def token = response.json.access_token

      then:
      token
     }
   }
   ```

Note: In Grails >= 3.0, `setup()` is run in a separate transaction and persisted (why it solves your problem) which is not rolled back.  Any data will need to be cleaned up manually.

I suggest you read the grails documentation on testing: [Integration Testing](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting)

Comment: Thank you! I had read the documentation thoroughly but I didn't realize that the transaction not being committed means that the user will not be able to be authenticated by Spring Security. I thought that it would be setup for the user upon `.save()` even if it's not persisted to the database. I've now moved the code to the `setup()` method and I can now perform the test.